# Is there an English word that means "to feel the call of the homeland"?

Tags: meaning, british-english

I seem to remember reading it once, sort of meaning the opposite of diaspora - once you have spread far, you would feel the X, the call to return to the homeland?

Comment: Suadade: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saudade

Comment: *Diaspora* would include descendants of the original migrants. Are you meaning **those** people feeling the call, or the original migrants? (Descendants are unlikely to feel *homesick,* because it was never their home.)

Comment: During World War I, "Dear Old Blighty" was a common sentimental reference, suggesting a longing for home by soldiers in the trenches.

Comment: @Josh61 Actually, [*saudade* is quite a bit more complicated](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/284/38) than just homesickness.

Comment: @tchrist - Yes, that's why I didn't make  answer, but it is often  with that meaning also.

Comment: Consider that "homeland" has no particular meaning to most in the US -- everyone is from somewhere else, and each "somewhere else" is different.  (In spite of the gaggingly-named "Homeland Security Agency".)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Yearning - it doesn't exactly mean feeling the call of the homeland
- Homesick - It's more about home Home, than homeland longing.
- Patriot - Lover of country/state, but does not indicate home.

I do not think there's a single specific word for it, though.

Maybe Saudade? Portuguese/Spanish in origin, no direct English translation - maybe it's time English took one of the foreign words that it loves doing (I recall someone saying English is a lovely, messy miasma of hodgepodge words and rules.). But i digress.

Answer (score 4):

Such a person is said to be feeling **homesick** or to have **homesickness**.

Comment: Almost what I was looking for but more a deeper call, less of a depressed feeling.

Comment: Homesick isn't depression, it's longing.

Answer (score 1):

How about ***nostalgia***?

> The condition of being homesick; homesickness. [FOD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Nostalgia)
>
> *Feel nostalgia for one's homeland*